# Implementing SAML 2.0 Authentication with Azure Directory Federation Service in React and Flask-RESTPlus

Tags: reactjs, authentication, flask, saml-2.0, adfs

I am working on a project where the core requirement is to implement SAML 2.0 authentication using an endpoint URL provided by Azure Directory Federation Service. The frontend of the application is built with React, and the routing is handled by React Router. The backend is developed using Flask-RESTPlus.

I would like to know how to integrate SAML 2.0 authentication into this setup. Are there any tutorials or guides available that can help me achieve this? Additionally, if there are any recommended packages or libraries that simplify the implementation process, I would greatly appreciate the suggestions.